# Ruby on rails unitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new at Ruby on Rails, and I am not quite sure what this error means:

```
uninitialized constant StorevaluesController
```

I have a storevalue_controller.rb which works (I can get to content on the page) but when I try to submit a form like this:

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Fill out form to add to db</h1>
<%= form_for :storevalue, url: storevalue_path do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

rails throws the error I reference above.

storevalue_controller.rb

```
class StorevalueController < ApplicationController
def new
end
def create
@storevalue = Storevalue.new(storevalue_params)
@storevalue.save
redirect_to @storevalue
end

def show
@storevalue = Storevalue.find(params[:id])
end

private
def storevalue_params
params.require(:storevalue).permit(:title, :text)
end
end
```

my route trace:

```
welcome_index_path    GET   /welcome/index(.:format)    welcome#index
root_path             GET   /   welcome#index
storevalue_new_path   GET   /storevalue/new(.:format)   storevalue#new
storevalue_path       POST  /storevalue(.:format)   storevalues#create
new_storevalue_path   GET   /storevalue/new(.:format)   storevalues#new
edit_storevalue_path  GET   /storevalue/edit(.:format)  storevalues#edit
GET     /storevalue(.:format)   storevalues#show
PATCH   /storevalue(.:format)   storevalues#update
PUT     /storevalue(.:format)   storevalues#update
DELETE  /storevalue(.:format)   storevalues#destroy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the error is plural "values" and your actual controller name is not. You're using the plural name somewhere when it doesn't exist. In Ruby, class names are constants. Hence you have the error message wording, which I agree is pretty misleading at face value.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably inferring the controller name dynamically within that call to `storevalue_path`. The Rails convention is to use plurals for controller names, so you should probably just rename it to `StorevaluesController`.